# Understanding Python Code Using Slicing

Tags: python, indexing, slice

So currently I am working on this and really trying to deeply understand it every step of the way! Currently I know that in line 3 that it gets changed to "Bungo Batgins" but on line 6 I am not sure why the/how the word changes to "Batgins, Bungo". I understand it is finding the space which is index 5 and then adds to index 6 to add the comma. I just dont quite understand why the two words flip? If someone could explain why the two words take each others place that would be great! Thank you very much!

```
word = "Bungo Baggins"
idx = word.find('gg')
word = word[ : idx] + 't' + word[idx + 1 : ]
idx = word.find(' ')
print(idx)
word = word[idx + 1 : ] + ", " + word[ : idx]
print(word)
```

Comment: In the second `word = ...` statement, the slicing parts are swapped...

Comment: So does word[idx+1:] is including Batgins only?

Comment: Indeed. You split in the space. And `word[idx+1:]` contains the slicing starting from the character **next** of that space...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line `word = word[idx + 1 : ] + ", " + word[ : idx]`, the right hand side translates to:

`word[idx + 1 : ]`: take each element of `word`, starting at `idx+1` until the end

`word[ : idx]`: take each element of `word` starting at the beginning and ending at `idx`.

Essentially, a missing index in `[a:b]` translates to the extremal index in that direction: `[:idx]` is really `[0:idx]` while `[idx:]` is really `[idx:end]`